# fopen() causing segfault before it's called

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, fopen

I am having a very weird error, I would try to run valgrind, but I am on OS X Yosemite, so this is not possible. I am getting a segfault with an fopen, it seems before the fopen is ever even called. I have a function called format:

```
void format(uint16_t sector_size, uint16_t cluster_size, uint16_t disk_size)
{ 
FILE *fp;
fp=fopen(diskName, "wb");
if(fp != NULL)
{
    printf("Disk successfully initialized at: %s",diskName);

}
else
{
    printf("There was an error creating the disk.");
    return;
}

for(int i=0;i<disk_size;i++)
{
    fwrite(0, sizeof(sector_size), cluster_size, fp);
}
}
```

Diskname is declared globally at the top of the file:

```
char diskName[32];
```

Here is my main:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
strcpy(diskName, "test.bin");
printf("%s",diskName);
format(128, 8, 1000);
}
```

The weird part is that, this code segfaults before it ever prints the diskname:

```
Run Command: line 1: 16016 Segmentation fault: 11
```

I have no idea how this is possible, and I've tried a wide-array of solutions, but it all boils down to an error with fopen. When fopen is commented out the code runs. Any idea why this would happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`printf` will buffer its output until you flush the output. This can be done by either printing a newline, or flushing the output using `fflush(stdout)`.

In any case, your error is here:

```
fwrite(0, sizeof(sector_size), cluster_size, fp);
```

You may not see your program crash when you comment out the `fopen` call because the `fwrite` call will fail earlier. `fwrite`'s signature expects a *pointer* to the data to write as the first argument, where you have provided zero. This will cause `fwrite` to attempt to dereference a NULL pointer and thus crash.

You can either allocate a buffer, set it all to zero, then write that to the file using `fwrite`, e.g.

```
char* buf = calloc(cluster_size, sector_size); // Remember, calloc initialises all elements to zero!
fwrite(buf, sector_size, cluster_size, fp);
```

Or just call `fputc` in a loop

```
for(int i = 0; i < sector_size * cluster_size; i++)
    fputc(0, fp);
```

Also, `sizeof(sector_size)` will *always* return 2 in your example, as you're taking the size of the type. Are you sure this is correct?

Comment: Hey, that worked with the printf! At least I know why that wasn't printing now. Would you happen to know why the fopen isn't working now? From my research I found a lot of errors result from trying to pass char literals instead of a string literal, but I am passing a string literal.

Comment: @Turtle-in-a-bash-shell Are you sure `fopen` is failing? See my answer for problems with the `fwrite` call, which may be the problem instead.

Comment: Good point! You are also right on `sector_size`, I should be using just `sector_size` instead of `sizeof(sector_size)`/

Comment: @Turtle-in-a-bash-shell - I don't know 100% what you're trying to achieve. I'd assume that you do just want `sector_size` though.

Comment: Hey, that did the trick! I commented out the fwrites and everything is working now - I will implement the writes the way you outlined. It only appeared like the `fopen()` was the problem because my prints were having the same newline problem you referenced earlier - the real culprit was `fwrite`. Thank you!

Comment: As for the sector_size, I am implementing a FAT file-system, sector_size, should be determined by the user.